# Почему TextView c TextStyle:bold не становится жирным?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Собственно ситуация такая, имеется TextView, у которого textStyle:bold, но текст не стал жирнее.Но вот при просмотре текст в  textView жирный.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и как ее устранить?

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="textView"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Возможно проблема в устройстве. Попробуйте запустить на эмуляторе. Если также, то приложите код разметки и как вы устанавливаете текст.

Comment: А что имеете ввиду под "при просмотре"?

Comment: уточнение, имеется некая layout которая используется в RecyclerView. на виртуальном и реальном устройствах результат один и тот же.

Comment: проблема решена, я программно задал жирность  personViewHolder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);